# How to include https in rewrite when using htaccess for routing friendly urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have found the proper htaccess code to rout friendly urls to my index.php file but it does not rout to https if the user inputs:

> example.com/sub-folder/rout/

***Note***: this particular re-write htaccess exists in a subfolder of the domain

my htaccess is:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # The basic rewrtie rule.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,E=X_REWRITE:1,L]

    # Add the proper X_REWRITE server variable for rewritten requests.
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_X_REWRITE} .+
    RewriteRule ^index\.php - [QSA,E=X_REWRITE:1,E=!REDIRECT_X_REWRITE,L]

    # 301 redirect urls that start with request.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/index\.php(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php %1%2 [QSA,R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I honestly do not understand the code enough to figure out what to do and thought I would try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/subfolder/index.php/$1 [QSA,E=X_REWRITE:1,L]
```

But that does not work.

How can I cause the re-write to go to https instead of http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this after any other rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

This will first enforce https before other rules are applied.

So your final .htaccess code becomes

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # The basic rewrtie rule.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,E=X_REWRITE:1,L]

    # Add the proper X_REWRITE server variable for rewritten requests.
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_X_REWRITE} .+
    RewriteRule ^index\.php - [QSA,E=X_REWRITE:1,E=!REDIRECT_X_REWRITE,L]

    # 301 redirect urls that start with request.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/index\.php(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php %1%2 [QSA,R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks!. So since I have 3 rewrite rules I would add it under each one correct?

Comment: This rewrites to https but when I have `example.com/subfolder/name` it rewrites to `https://example.com/index.php/name` 
If I just have `example.com/subfoler` it will correctly re-write to `https://example.com/subfolder` . but I need the additional name parameter

Comment: No.Just add it above all other rewrite rules... I will update my answer to make it clear